# Google Places Autocomplete with Floatingsearchview

Tags: java, android, google-places-api

Good Morning,
I currently have a custom [Google places autocomplete](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-places/tree/master/PlaceCompleteAdapter/Application/src/main/java/com/example/google/playservices/placecomplete) running with AutoCompleteTextView, but I need to implement it with the following library [Floatingsearchview](https://github.com/arimorty/floatingsearchview), But I can not find the way to do it, let's see if you can help me.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Use this

```
try {
    Intent intent =
            new PlaceAutocomplete.IntentBuilder(PlaceAutocomplete.MODE_OVERLAY)
                    .build(this);
    startActivityForResult(intent, PLACE_AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE);
} catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
    // TODO: Handle the error.
} catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
    // TODO: Handle the error.
}
```

> Result on place selected

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == PLACE_AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Place place = PlaceAutocomplete.getPlace(this, data);
            Log.i(TAG, "Place: " + place.getName());
        } else if (resultCode == PlaceAutocomplete.RESULT_ERROR) {
            Status status = PlaceAutocomplete.getStatus(this, data);
            // TODO: Handle the error.
            Log.i(TAG, status.getStatusMessage());

        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // The user canceled the operation.
        }
    }
}
```

> Link https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/autocomplete#get_place_predictions_programmatically

Answer (score 0):

From the sample of the floatingsearchview here https://github.com/arimorty/floatingsearchview/blob/master/sample/src/main/java/com/arlib/floatingsearchviewdemo/data/DataHelper.java it provide custom filter to the adapter. I believe you can use AutocompletePrediction model from Google API.

Please see sample here
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-places/tree/master/PlaceCompleteAdapter How they use custom filter with Google API and ArrayAdapter. You can just provide the custom filter in this sample to floatingsearchview.